# Silverlight 5 and OpenFileDialogue

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight 4 app out-of-browser with elevated trust settings and I can only access  files that are located in special folders (My Documents, My pictures, etc..)

Is there a way to access the whole local file system using Silverlight 5 with open file dialog box without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to have [Trusted Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.96%29.aspx) for that

> Specifically, Silverlight 5 trusted applications can do the following:
>
> - Access the local file system without restrictions.
>
> ...