# Check if I have write access to folder in Silverlight 5 Out of Browser Elevated Trust

Tags: c#, silverlight, filesystems, silverlight-5.0

How can I check in a Silverlight 5 OoB Application with Elevated Trust if I can write in a certain user-selected folder?
At the moment I attempted to create and delete a folder, if no exception occurs I have write access.

```
   try {
     CreateSubDirectory(path, newDir);
     DeleteSubDir(path, newDir);
     writeAccess = true;
   } catch(Exception) {
     writeAccess = false;
   }
```

I searched in the documentation and didn't found any less hacky way of doing it. How do you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've found, you don't have much choice, try/catch is the way to go.

But you should catch with much more precision. You want to be able to tell between IOException, SecurityException and other exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check to see if your app has elevated privileges.

```
if (Application.Current.HasElevatedPermissions)
{
    // Do File IO here
}
```

These articles have some more information:
[How to: Access the Local File System in Trusted Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721082%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
[Trusted Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I need. I prompt the user to select a folder from his filesystem and I need to know if the application can write files to that folder. I already know I have elevated privileges.

Comment: Perhaps this question is the answer?
[Silverlight 5 and OpenFileDialogue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477320/silverlight-5-and-openfiledialogue)